# vim with wdiff?

Tags: vim

I am merging text (not code) using vim. Unfortunately, the paragraph formatting is different between the two text. I know if I used `wdiff` it would only show the differences that I am interested in, but to edit the text, I'd like to use diff-mode in vim. A quick search in the vim help and vim wiki gives me no hits. What would be a good way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2):

This morning I found an [awesome Gist](https://gist.github.com/ynkdir/1633233) that does what you ask (w/o a wdiff dependency no less!). It could use a little polish in that you must specify the `winnr()` for each window you want to compare, but does basically what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Without having `wdiff` I cannot give you an actual working example, but I suggest you read through "`:help diff-diffexpr`" and try modifying the example shown there to use `wdiff`.

However, if this works at all, you may still find yourself needing to do "`:diffupdate`" frequently.